# Copy animation from rigify to armature created from scratch

Tags: rigging, keyframes, rigify

Hello Blender community!
I created an animation in a rigify rig but now I want to copy its keyframes to a rig I created from scratch on my own. Is this possible?

Comment: your own armature needs to have bones that has the same names as the original

Comment: yes I know that but I created a rig with less bones than the autogenerated metarig of Blender and it doesn't work.